# Use "Terminal" instead of "Debug Console" as the I/O feed, when debugging in Visual Studio Code

Tags: go, debugging, visual-studio-code

Is it possible to debug Go files on VS code using the Terminal as the I/O feed for the debugging process instead of the Debug Console (like with Nodejs for example)? A special config on `launch.json` perhaps?

Current behavior:

[image]

Desired behavior:

[image]

Comment: `"console": "integratedTerminal"`. You can also set `"externalTerminal"`

Comment: Awesome! Thanks. You can leave this comment as an answer if you want so I can select it as the correct one and you get the points. @Hana

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`"console": "integratedTerminal"` or `"console": "externalTerminal"` in your launch.json configuration.

This is a relatively new feature that was added to Go extension v0.31.0 (Jan 2022).